# Python 3.6.5 urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to download a csv file from the internet. Here is my code using urllib. But I get HTTP Error 403.

**Program-1:**

```
from urllib import request
nse_stocks = 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv'

def download_file(url):
    connection = request.urlopen(url)
    file_read = connection.read()
    file_str = str(file_read)
    lines_file_str = file_str.split('\\n')
    file = open(r'downloaded_file.csv', 'w')
    for line in lines_file_str:
        file.write(line + '\n')
    file.close()
download_file(nse_stocks)
```

**Response:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sg0205481/Documents/Krishna/eBooks/Python/TheNewBoston/Python/downloadWebFile2.py", line 17, in <module>
    download_file(nse_stocks)
  File "C:/Users/sg0205481/Documents/Krishna/eBooks/Python/TheNewBoston/Python/downloadWebFile2.py", line 7, in download_file
    connection = request.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\sg0205481\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\sg0205481\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\sg0205481\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\sg0205481\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sg0205481\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sg0205481\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

But I don't get the error with Program-2 with requests module. File gets downloaded successfully.

**Program-2:**

```
import requests

def download_file(url):
    file_data = requests.get(url)
    filename = 'downloaded_file.csv'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(file_data.content)


download_file('https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv')
```

What is the problem with Program-1? What makes Program-2 pass successfully?

Comment: The server does.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file (mime type) with get method from web server, not post method. If web server has handler for this extension and accept post method, than you may try!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rajib. I am still a novice in Programming. Can you help me understand the cause of the error in Program-1 and how it can be resolved?